# MacBook Pro Freezing

Tags: screen

My MacBook Pro just started acting up. The screen will flicker and I end up having to reboot my computer. I can still move the mouse around, but that's just about it. Would you have any ideas what the problem may be?

Comment: This is nearly impossible to answer without some details. Perhaps check the Console for anything suspicious?

Comment: More details would really be helpful. Is the computer still responding to keyboard input, are the fans running on high speed, is some special processing/application running

Answer (score 1):

Suggestions:

- Run Mac in [recovery mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4718) (keep holding <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> on startup), then try to Repair Disk and Repair Disk Permissions using Disk Utility.
- As suggested in [Mountain Lion Screen Freeze](https://discussions.apple.com/message/22435748#22435748) thread, try OnyX software which allows and to verify the startup disk and the structure of its system files, etc.
- Run *dmesg* and check `/var/log/system.log` for more detailed errors.
- Run Console app to check crash logs including backtraces if any.
- Run `newproc.d` or `iofile.d` *dtrace* scripts to find anything suspicious (e.g. `sudo newproc.d`)

<sup>Related:</sup>
<sup>Apple.SE: [Mountain Lion Screen Freeze](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/102148/mountain-lion-screen-freeze)</sup>
<sup>Apple Discussions: [Mountain Lion Screen Freeze](https://discussions.apple.com/message/23008819) (over 177 replies)</sup>