# Mountain Lion Screen Freeze

Tags: crash, performance, logs, kernel

My Mountain Lion is keeps freezing from few weeks, today it freezes/crashed couple of times already.

Here is the log before the big freeze (file /var/log/system.log):

```
SIMBL Enabler for Sandboxed Apps[3334]: Will terminate until reinvoked again by launchd.
com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[265] (com.apple.pbs[3243]): Exited: Killed: 9
kernel[0]: memorystatus_thread: idle exiting pid 3243 [pbs]
com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.iCloudHelper[3241]): Exited: Killed: 9
kernel[0]: memorystatus_thread: idle exiting pid 3241 [com.apple.iCloud]
com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpcd.F5010000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000[3238]): Exited: Killed: 9
kernel[0]: memorystatus_thread: idle exiting pid 3238 [xpcd]
com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.sleepservicesd[3237]): Exited: Killed: 9
kernel[0]: memorystatus_thread: idle exiting pid 3237 [SleepServicesD]
com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[265] (com.apple.CalendarAgent[3188]): Exited: Killed: 9
kernel[0]: memorystatus_thread: idle exiting pid 3188 [CalendarAgent]
kernel[0]: (default pager): [KERNEL]: ps_select_segment - send HI_WAT_ALERT
kernel[0]: macx_swapon SUCCESS
com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.sleepservicesd[3362]): Exited: Killed: 9
kernel[0]: memorystatus_thread: idle exiting pid 3362 [SleepServicesD]
SubmitDiagInfo[3240]: Launched to submit Diagnostics and Usage
com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.cfprefsd.xpc.daemon[3235]): Exited: Killed: 9
kernel[0]: memorystatus_thread: idle exiting pid 3235 [cfprefsd]
WindowServer[222]: reenable_update_for_connection: UI updates were finally reenabled by application "Activity Monitor" after 125.95 seconds (server forcibly re-enabled them after 1.00 seconds)
com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.sleepservicesd[3364]): Exited: Killed: 9
kernel[0]: memorystatus_thread: idle exiting pid 3364 [SleepServicesD]
coreaudiod[249]: Disabled automatic stack shots because audio IO is active
coreaudiod[249]: Enabled automatic stack shots because audio IO is inactive
com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[265] (com.apple.pbs[3369]): Exited: Killed: 9
kernel[0]: memorystatus_thread: idle exiting pid 3369 [pbs]
com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.sleepservicesd[3368]): Exited: Killed: 9
kernel[0]: memorystatus_thread: idle exiting pid 3368 [SleepServicesD]
com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.cfprefsd.xpc.daemon[3366]): Exited: Killed: 9
com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[265] (com.apple.cfprefsd.xpc.agent[3225]): Exited: Killed: 9
kernel[0]: memorystatus_thread: idle exiting pid 3366 [cfprefsd]
kernel[0]: memorystatus_thread: idle exiting pid 3225 [cfprefsd]
com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.sleepservicesd[3387]): Exited: Killed: 9
kernel[0]: memorystatus_thread: idle exiting pid 3387 [SleepServicesD]
com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.locationd[3191]): Exited with code: 1
com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.sleepservicesd[3388]): Exited: Killed: 9
kernel[0]: memorystatus_thread: idle exiting pid 3388 [SleepServicesD]
locationd[3405]: Incorrect NSStringEncoding value 0x8000100 detected. Assuming NSASCIIStringEncoding. Will stop this compatiblity mapping behavior in the near future.
locationd[3405]: NOTICE,Location icon should now be in state 0
locationd[3405]: locationd was started after an unclean shutdown
com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.sleepservicesd[3406]): Exited: Killed: 9
kernel[0]: memorystatus_thread: idle exiting pid 3406 [SleepServicesD]
com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.cfprefsd.xpc.daemon[3407]): Exited: Killed: 9
kernel[0]: memorystatus_thread: idle exiting pid 3407 [cfprefsd]
com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.sleepservicesd[3408]): Exited: Killed: 9
kernel[0]: memorystatus_thread: idle exiting pid 3408 [SleepServicesD]
com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.sleepservicesd[3412]): Exited: Killed: 9
kernel[0]: memorystatus_thread: idle exiting pid 3412 [SleepServicesD]
kernel[0]: (default pager): [KERNEL]: ps_select_segment - send HI_WAT_ALERT
kernel[0]: memorystatus_thread: idle exiting pid 3416 [SleepServicesD]
com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.sleepservicesd[3416]): Exited: Killed: 9
kernel[0]: macx_swapon SUCCESS
WindowServer[222]: CGXDisableUpdate: UI updates were forcibly disabled by application "Finder" for over 1.00 seconds. Server has re-enabled them.
WindowServer[222]: reenable_update_for_connection: UI updates were finally reenabled by application "Finder" after 11.80 seconds (server forcibly re-enabled them after 1.23 seconds)
kernel[0]: memorystatus_thread: idle exiting pid 3448 [SleepServicesD]
com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.sleepservicesd[3448]): Exited: Killed: 9
bootlog[0]: BOOT_TIME 1379512956 0
kernel[0]: Darwin Kernel Version 12.4.0: Wed May  1 17:57:12 PDT 2013; root:xnu-2050.24.15~1/RELEASE_X86_64
```

It seems that the most of the processes are killed by unknown reason.
This is happening even after fresh restart and open few Chrome web-browser tabs.
Based on the logs, it seems like MACX Swap is started to be used, despite of 4GB memory.
I've checked the high usage in Activity Monitor, and the highest were kernel and mds with around 800MB usage. There is plenty of space on HDD (SDD).

This problem is widely experienced, so please don't underestimate it.

Related:

[Mountain Lion Screen Freeze](https://discussions.apple.com/message/23008819) (over 177 replies)

[MacBook Pro Freezing](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/53981/macbook-pro-freezing)

Please state the solutions and tests which can be performed on the software level, etc.
What can be done to track the most common issues like that.

Comment: It looks like your RAM is failing? Test it!

Comment: How can you test RAM?

Comment: Which one are incomplete? I've removed datetime prefixes for clearer view.

Comment: Memory test http://osxdaily.com/2011/05/03/memtest-mac-ram-test/    for the second question give me a moment to compile the list of incomplete words in your log

Comment: I think the problem with incomplete words is on my side :( at first local coreaudiod[249]: Enabled automatic stack shots because ??tive  but after page reload it is fixed...sorry

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you using the SIMBL Enabler?

Comment: SIMBLAgent is used by aFloat (http://infinite-labs.net/aFloat/) which supports transparency and on-top feature. It's quite useful, but I had few crashes with it: https://code.google.com/p/simbl/issues/detail?id=69

Comment: What was the result of the RAM test?

Comment: Exited: Killed: 9 =  SIGKILL
    The SIGKILL signal is sent to a process to cause it to terminate immediately (kill). In contrast to SIGTERM and SIGINT, this signal cannot be caught or ignored, and the receiving process cannot perform any clean-up upon receiving this signal.

Comment: Tested RAM with Rember app, it didn't find anything wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggestions:

- Run `kill -CONT -1` command to unfreeze any potential pauzed/frozen applications.
- Run Mac in [recovery mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4718) (keep holding <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> on startup), then try to Repair Disk and Repair Disk Permissions using Disk Utility.
- As suggested in [Mountain Lion Screen Freeze](https://discussions.apple.com/message/22435748#22435748) thread, try OnyX software which allows and to verify the startup disk and the structure of its system files, etc.
- Run *dmesg* and check `/var/log/system.log` for more detailed errors.
- Run Console app to check crash logs including backtraces if any.
- Run `newproc.d` or `iofile.d` *dtrace* scripts to find anything suspicious (e.g. `sudo newproc.d`)
- Run memory test (e.g. using [Rember](http://www.kelleycomputing.net/Rember/) app)